# How do you display list of admin with is_admin attribute in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

How do you display all list of admin that have column with the `is_admin=1`? with this query? because we are not passing any data in showListAdmin.

```
public function Admin()
    {
        $users = User::all();
        return view('admin.admins')->with('users',$users);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply use [where](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#where-clauses) ....

```
public function showListAdmin()
    {
        $users = User::where('is_admin',true)->get()->all();
        return view('admin.admins')->with('users',$users);
    }
```

Comment: thank you sir but instead of using `all()` I use `get()`  because it will throw the error `undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::all()`

Comment: you are right , you can use all() after get() to make the result an array